# How to get a table data element using the id?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to grab the inner text of an  element. I have tried many approaches to this and still can't fully understand why this is not working.

I have already tried grabbing it by the class, by the id and even by the type of element.

I expected the function to run, but instead it gets caught in the problem areas I marked within the javascript.

```js
function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartItemContainer = document.getElementById('cart-table')
  var cartRows = cartItemContainer.rows.length
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 1; i < cartRows; i++) {
    var cartRow = cartRows[i]
    var priceElement = cartRow.getElementById('item-total')[0] //this is the issue ALSO: i have tried removing "[0]"
    var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0] //this is the issue ALSO: i have tried removing "[0]"
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''))
    var quantity = quantityElement.value
    total = total + (price * quantity)
  }
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
  document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '$' + total
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-border checkout-table" id="cart-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/intro-04.jpg" alt="[Rainbow Six] Complete Edition" /></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5 class="txt25">[Rainbow Six] Complete Edition</h5>
      </td>
      <td class="txt25" id="item-total">
        $45.00
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="" value="1" max="50" min="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="item-total-total txt25">
        $45.00
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeRow(this)" type="button">REMOVE</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please use tags only for what the code concerns. There is no `c#`, nor `php`, nor `c++` here and I sincerely doubt this problem concerns *any* of those.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant script and html to make a [mcve]

Comment: .getElementById will return a single element and the IDs must be unique

Comment: It seems that `cartRow` is the length of `carItemContainer` and does not contain any actual elements. `cartRow.getElementById('item-total')` should more like be something like `document.getElementById('item-total')`

Comment: @mplungjan also, it's only available at `document`, not from random nodes.

Comment: @VLAZ - yeah. I suggested querySelector instead in my answer

Comment: @mplungjan I only mentioned the `document` thing because I came upon it last week or so. I tried `someNode.getElementById()` and was surprised it didn't work. I had to look it up and found it's only at `document` level. Which makes some sense - IDs are supposed to be unique, so if you want to look something up by ID, you would have to do it globally. I did end up using `querySelector` in my case, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- getElementById is only on document, not other nodes
- document.getElementById('item-total') will return ONE element and
- IDs must be unique.
- I changed `<td class="txt25" id="item-total">` to `<td class="txt25 item-total">`
- I also suggest you change `class="cart-total-price"` to `id="cart-total-price"` since there is likely only one

Try classes and querySelector which is superior to getElementsByClassName:

```
function updateCartTotal() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('cart-table tbody tr')].forEach((cartRow) => {
    var price = cartRow.querySelector('.item-total').innerText.replace(/[$\s]/g,"")
    var quantity = cartRow.querySelector('.form-control').value;
    total += (+price * +quantity)
  });
  document.querySelector('.cart-total-price').innerText = '$' + total.toFixed(2)
}
```

For older browser support you can change first line to

```
var cartRows = document.querySelectorAll('cart-table tbody tr')
for (var i=0, cartRow;i<cartRows.length; i++) {
  cartRow = cartRows[i];
```

Comment: I think you can just briefly describe what OP's current problem was, so they know what was wrong. (actually was just writing this comment when you asked me above)